# Getting error while creating wordcloud in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am getting below error on running this code, any idea how to fix it?

**Code:**

```
library(wordcloud)
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
wordcloud(worst_corpus, min.freq = 100,
          max.words = 100,
          random.order = FALSE) #create wordcloud
```

**Error:**

> Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
>      In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>       2: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your data? It's easier for others to help if they can see your data and reproduce your problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to post reproducible data in your question.

Comment: check is there NA's in worst_corpus ?